# Angular HttpResponse<boolean> returns boolean value, not the expected HttpResponse

Tags: angular, httpresponse

I have an angular method calling a NodeJS API. I expected the return object to be an HttpResponse with a body type of boolean, but it returns a boolean. what am I missing?

Output (from console.log in the Angular API call): `true`

Expected: `{statusCode:200, headers:..., body: true}`

**Angular API call**

```
this.lsvc.login(login,pwd).subscribe((x:HttpResponse<boolean>)=>{
  console.log(JSON.stringify(x))
  if(x)   //<--------expected to need x.body
    alert('login success')
  else
    alert('login failed')
})
```

**Angular Service (calls JS API)**

```
   public login(user,pwd): Observable<HttpResponse<boolean>> {
     console.log('login: '+user+' '+pwd)
       return this.httpClient.post<HttpResponse<boolean>>(this.lambdaUrl+'login',{"email":user,"password":pwd}).pipe(
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
   }
```

**NodeJS API:**

```
'use strict';
module.exports.login = async event => {

  try{
    var obj=JSON.parse(event.body);  
    if(obj.email=='xx' && obj.password=='xxxx')
      return {statusCode: 200, headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},body: JSON.stringify(true)};
    return {statusCode: 200, headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},body: JSON.stringify(false)};
  }
  catch(e)
  {
    return {statusCode: 500, headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},body: JSON.stringify(e)+''};
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Angular http client module will return response body only, in case if you want all http response like headers status and body you have to use observe option, please check [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

```
 getConfigResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
   return this.http.get<Config>(
     this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, Angular HttpClient returns only the body of the success response. In case of an error, the complete HttpErrorResponse is returned. If the complete HttpResponse is needed, HttpClient provides an additional configuration. This is the third parameter to the `HttpClient.post` method - options. You can use `observe: 'response'` in the options to get the complete HttpResponse object ([Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)). You will have to modify your angular service to include this.

```
public login(user,pwd): Observable<HttpResponse<boolean>> {
    console.log('login: '+user+' '+pwd)
    return this.httpClient.post<HttpResponse<boolean>>(this.lambdaUrl+'login',{"email":user,"password":pwd}, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```